# ChiSquare test Code in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I was trying to write a code from scratch for Chi-square test.This is the code that I had written in python using pandas.I had a doubt whether the code can produce the desired output or can be written in a more compacted way.

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy import chisqprob
from scipy import stats

def chi_square_of_df_cols(main_frame,column1,column2):
    grouped_data=pd.DataFrame(main_frame.groupby([column1,column2])[column1].count())    
    grouped_data.columns=["count"]
    grouped_data.reset_index(inplace=True)
    pivoted_data=grouped_data.pivot(column1,column2,"count")
    pivoted_data.fillna(0,inplace=True)
    frame = pivoted_data.copy(deep="True")
    cols=pivoted_data.columns
    sum_row = {col: pivoted_data[col].sum() for col in pivoted_data}
    dof=(len(pivoted_data.columns)*len(pivoted_data))-1  
    pivoted_data["Total_row"] = pivoted_data.sum(axis=1)
    grid_total=pivoted_data["Total_row"].sum(axis=0)   
    for col in cols:
        for i in pivoted_data.index:
            frame.ix[i,col]= (pivoted_data.ix[i,"Total_row"])*(sum_row[col])/grid_total   

    sum1=0
    for col in cols:
        for i in pivoted_data.index:
            sum1+=(pivoted_data.ix[i,col]-frame.ix[i,col])**2/frame.ix[i,col]    

    p_value=chisqprob(sum1,dof)        

    return p_value
```